# How to mock CrudRepository the right way?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mocking

I am new to Spring. My GCGood class is saved with a CrudRepository to a MySQL-DB. And it works fine.

Now I try to write the JUnit-Test. Of course I dont want any test-data to be in my Database. So I wrote my Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class GCGoodTests {

    @MockBean
    private GCGoodRepository goodRepository;

    @Test
    public void getterSetterTest()
    {
        GCGood testDummy = new GCGod();
        testDummy.setAttribute("Muhaha");
        testDummy.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        testDummy.setName("Maka");
        testDummy = goodRepository.save(testDummy);
        Iterable<GCGood> testDummy2 = goodRepository.findAll();
        assertEquals(testDummy.getAttribute(), "Muhaha");
        assertEquals(testDummy.getColor(), Color.BLACK);
        assertEquals(testDummy.getName(), "Maka");
        assertNotNull(testDummy.getId());
        assert(testDummy.getId()>0);
        assertNotNull(testDummy2);
    }
}
```

Unfortuantelly "*testDummy = goodRepository.save(testDummy);*" and "*Iterable testDummy2 = goodRepository.findAll();*" return null and the tests dont even finish.

If I change @MockBean to @Autowire, everything works fine. But I have unnecessary data-shmodda in my database.

So, how do I achieve corret test without data-shmodda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to do an integration test. If so, you should use `@DataJpaTest` annotation which creates for you environment when tests can run using in memory database. More you can find out in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test).

It also depends what you want to test. If repository (GCGoodRepository) is your test target you should `@Autowired` it and use some in memory database to test it in an isolated environment as I mentioned above. If you test some service which depends on some repository (eg. GCGoodRepository) you should mock this repository as @karthi mentioned.

Comment: Thank you! That "in memory database" issue was the problem. With @DataJpaTest it works fine!

Answer (score 2):

Though you have injected the mocked-bean you have not actually mentioned the method which has to be mocked and what you expect if you do call some method on the mocked-bean. What you can do is , just write the @Before method like this:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
        List<GCGood> gcgoods = Collections.emptyList();
        given(goodRepository.findAll()).willAnswer(gcgoods);
}
```

The given() and willAnswer() are in the BDDMockito, which you can import through import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.*;

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But I did not want to mock only special functions, but transfer the DB to "in memory" as lucascode suggested!